# Unable to execute insert operation into Sql Azure db through Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure

So I'm trying to simply logg some stuff from Azure Function to a database.
My code looks like this below

I've managed to see that the error is generated at the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() because my log.information shows

```
2019-05-29T11:21:45.149 [Info] First Stop
2019-05-29T11:21:45.149 [Info] Connection Made
2019-05-29T11:21:45.149 [Info] Open Connection
2019-05-29T11:21:45.149 [Info] Create Query InsertInto
2019-05-29T11:21:45.149 [Info] enter SQL Command cmd
2019-05-29T11:21:45.149 [Info] insert a log to the database
2019-05-29T11:21:45.160 [Info] Function completed (Success, Id=7e507164-a17d-4aa7-84bd-279e0934514e, Duration=261ms)

using System.Net;
using Dapper;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


[FunctionName("CreateLoggsToDbWithAzureFunctions")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# HTTP trigger function processed a request. RequestUri={req.RequestUri}");

    var successful =true;

    try
    {
        log.LogInformation("First Stop");
        var cnnString  = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sqldb_connection"].ConnectionString;

        //Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("sqldb_connection");
        log.LogInformation("Connection Made", cnnString);
        using(var connection = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            log.LogInformation("Open Connection");

            //var rLog = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<LogRequest>();

            log.LogInformation("Create Query InsertInto");

                    var query = "INSERT INTO Loggs (LogError)";
                    query += "VALUES (@LogError)";


                        log.LogInformation("enter SQL Command cmd");
                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                        log.LogInformation("insert a log to the database");
                        var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        log.LogInformation("Log added to database successfully!");
                }
                //connection.Execute(query, rLog);             

            // insert a log to the database
            // NOTE: Execute is an extension method from Dapper library
            //connection.Execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Loggs] ([LogError]) VALUES (@LogError)", rLog);
            //log.LogInformation("Log added to database successfully!");
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        successful=false;
    }

    return !successful
        ? req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Unable to process your request!")
        : req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Data saved successfully!");
}
public class LogRequest
{   
    //public string Id{get;set;}
    //public string Date{get;set;}
    //public string LogCritical{get;set;}
    //public string LogDebug{get;set;}
    public string LogError{get;set;}
    //public string LogInformation{get;set;} 
    //public string LogTrace{get;set;}
    //public string LogWarning{get;set;}
}
```

I have tried different methods like using dapper and creating 
 connection.Execute(query, rLog);
or doing

```
connection.Execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Loggs] ([LogError]) VALUES (@LogError)", rLog);`
```

But there is nothing saved to the database and I do get the message

```
2019-05-29T11:21:45.160 [Info] Function completed
```

But nothing happens, does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your parameter like this:

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogError", "ACTUAL ERROR");`

Comment: Thanks for the input but I'm still stuck at the same problem even with your parameter add new change looks like this


                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogError", e.LogError);

                        log.LogInformation("Log added to database successfully!");
                

All "works" and runs but nothing is stored to the database :(
The last loginformation is shown 
2019-05-30T05:38:45.401 [Info] Log added to database successfully!

Comment: have you tried to insert a simple string? I don't see where the "e.LogError" is coming from in your code

Comment: sorry for late response but I tried to serilize the inc body to string. Saw that in a poste like this :   dynamic body = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                 var e = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogRequest>(body as string);
there is where e.LogError is coming from. I tried to enter

Comment: Missed the second Q  - I manage to insert inteo the DB with this  "string insert = "string insert =  "INSERT INTO Loggs (ID, Date, LogCritical,LogDebug,LogError,LogInformation,LogTrace,LogWarning)" + "VALUES (6,'2018-05-31','Crit','Debug','Error','info','Trace','Warning')";;" 
 using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert, connection))
                {var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    }

Comment: But as soon as I use this statment instead it wont work ( " string insert = "INSERT INTO Loggs (ID, Date, LogCritical,LogDebug,LogError,LogInformation,LogTrace,LogWarning)VALUES(@ID,@Date,@LogCritical,@LogDebug,@LogError,@LogInformation,@LogTrace,@LogWarning)";")

Comment: Try to use the same insert that worked but use it with parameters. set all the values to exactly the same values that worked for you so it will be: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LogError", "ERROR"); cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 6); etc.

Comment: I don't know your table constraints so maybe just use a different value for ID (guess this is your primary key which should be unique)